# running a washer drain

Tags: plumbing, drain

I need to move my washer to the other side of my basement. Approximately 25 feet away from my sewer line. I need to go up to my floor joists, forward 2 joists and from there I'm able to run along the joist and then down and then run my grade along the foundation wall to my sewer line.

I'm not able to run along the wall the entire way due to my panel box being located in the corner to the left of where the washer will be installed. My question is hooking in the drain line and the p trap location. I know my washer is able to pump 8'. So am I able to run my drain from a hookup box down to a P and straight back up into the joists, or would it be better to run and extended drain line from the washer up to the joists and have the p trap installed between the joists and if so how would I go about doing so to have the line in enough to properly drain.

Comment: A trap only functions properly if it's vented. Neither described scenario involves a vent, and you may also require an air gap.

Answer (score 1):

Neither idea that you put forth will work, at least as I understand it.  You need to install a pumping system.